# getting an error in ethers.js deploy script

Tags: contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat, nodejs

My code is

```js
const path = require("path")
const { ethers } = require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")
const fs = require("fs")
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = async () => {
    const byteCode =
        "0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c806367e0badb14602d575b600080fd5b60336047565b604051603e91906067565b60405180910390f35b60008054905090565b6000819050919050565b6061816050565b82525050565b6000602082019050607a6000830184605a565b9291505056fea2646970667358221220bf589d7b8b1882fd287f7f8bf62502781345ff7839575c8bf210dfe6eeb2e48864736f6c63430008110033"

    const getTheAbiOfTest = () => {
        try {
            const dir = path.resolve(
                "/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/artifacts/Test.sol/Test.json"
            )
            const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8")
            const json = JSON.parse(file)
            const abi = json.abi

            return abi
            console.log(`the abi: ${abi}`)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`error ${e}`)
        }
    }

    //const [_abi, _byteCode] = getTheAbiOfTest()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
        process.env.JSON_RPC_PROVIDER
    )
    const signer = await provider.getSigner()

    const contractFactory = await ethers.ContractFactory(byteCode,getTheAbiOfTest() , signer)
    console.log(`contractFactory is ${contractFactory}`)

    const testContract = await contractFactory.deploy()
    console.log(`deployed`)
    console.log(`address of the testContract is : ${testContract.address}`)

    await testContract.deployTransaction.wait()

    console.log(`connecting to the contract....`)

    const test = new ethers.Contract(
        testContract.address,
        getTheAbiOfTest(),
        signer
    )
    console.log(`address of the test instance ${test.address}`)

    const num = await test.getNum()
    console.log(`num is: ${num}`)
}
```

When i run `hh deploy --network goerli` i am getting this error -

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/deploy/deploy.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'providers')
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/deploy/deploy.js:111:30)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:41)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/abinash/Desktop/DEX2/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:669:5)
```

Why i'm getting this error??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy to a testnet with ethers you will need to pass the private key to instantiate the deployment signer:

```
import * as hre from 'hardhat';

const provider = hre.ethers.provider;
const privKey = process.env['PRIVATE_KEY'] as BytesLike;
const deployer_wallet = new Wallet(privKey);
const deployer = await deployer_wallet.connect(provider);
```

Hope it helps